# How to type this symbol in LaTeX for Structural Causal Model?

Tags: symbols

[image]

How to type this symbol in LaTex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: General information on identifying symbols and math letters is found in this question: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the `amssymb` package and type `\mathfrak{C}` in math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\begin{document}
$\mathfrak{C}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked!